# node.js does not flush buffers on a crash

Tags: node.js

I am running node as a windows service. The service was crashing on startup so I implemented a logging system, to discover that messages do not get written to a file when the application is forced to exit. I have been able to duplicate the problem with the code below:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var logStream = fs.createWriteStream('./nx3.log');
logStream.end('Goodbye world');
process.exit(0);
```

Nothing is written into nx3.log because the buffers don't flush. I have been able to work around the problem by using fs.appendFileSync but I would prefer to be using a mature logging module rather than rolling my own.

Is it possible to open up a write stream that is unbuffered? Or some other way around this?

Comment: What logging module _have_ you been using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is not related to the buffer. The FS writeableStream performs the writes asynchronously. So `process.exit` is not waiting for `logSteam.end` to perform the write, rather it is exiting immediately.

What you can do, is listen on the `uncaughtException` event, and perform your logging there. If a listener is added for this exception, the default action (which is to print a stack trace and exit) will not occur.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
       logStream.end(err, function() {
           // write has completed, now we can exit
           process.exit(0);
       });
   });
```

Comment: Interesting, I had not come across uncaughtException. Thanks.

Comment: Only synchronous operations are allowed within `uncaughtException`. It's not safe to return from the `uncaughtException` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, the callback of `end()` is listening to `finish` event which DOES NOT implies buffer have been flushed into the output (e.g. disk or network).

So, `end()` will

1. emit `finish`
2. flush data
3. emit `end`

So, listen to `end` event from stream to be sure, like this example:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  // Use logStream to log what you want
  logStream.write(err);

  // Exit process only after flushing data
  logStream.writeStream.once('end', () => process.exit(1));
  logStream.end();
});
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end